# Is it possible to publish to FTP after TFS Build Server succeded?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, msbuild

So my problem is that i can successfully make TFS Build server to build my solution, but when TFS are trying to push the built code to FTP i get this error :

```
     C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FTP.targets (42): This specific WebPublishMethod(FTP) is not yet supported on msbuild command line.  Please use Visual Studio to publish.
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Deploy\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Deploy.FTP.targets (48): Target WebFTPPublish Failed
```

here is my MSBuild Arguments :  `/p:TransformConfigFiles=True /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:PublishProfile="Development" /p:Password="funkyCode"/p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Having no personal experience here, "...is not yet supported on msbuild command line. Please use Visual Studio..." seems pretty obvious. ;-) Apparently you just cannot do that from a command line build (which a TFS-Build is of course).

Answer (score 0):

You should switch to a PowerShell solution. If create a PowerShell to reply your app over FTP you can have it called by the build template.

In both DefaultTemplate.11.1.xaml and *Template.12.xaml you will find four locations that you can have the build run PowerShell. Use the post-test location.